# Get data from column when update is performed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I have three tables `OldTable`, `NewTable` and `MainTable`. I have made a trigger that puts old values in `OldTable` and new values in `Newtable`.

I need to get only changed data.

MainTable

```
EID Ename   EAddress    Emobile
1   mittal  pardi       9876543212
2   vaibhav Porbandar   7456543212
```

OLD TABLE

```
ID  EID Ename   EAddress    Emobile     CurrentDate
1   2   vaibhav pardi       7456543212  2017-12-21 11:00:23.437
```

NEW TABLE

```
ID  EID Ename   EAddress    Emobile     CurrentDate
1   2   vaibhav Porbandar   7456543212  2017-12-21 11:00:23.437
```

What I need:

```
EID OldValue  NewValue  
2   pardi     Porbandar
```

There can be more than one new and old value!

My trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_TEST_Upd]
ON [dbo].[MAIN_TABLE]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    begin
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED -- show data in INSERTED logical table
    SELECT * FROM DELETED -- show data in DELETED logical table

    insert into New_TABLE(EID,Ename,EAddress,Emobile,CurrentDate)               
                select  EID,Ename,EAddress,Emobile,getdate() from INSERTED


     insert into  OLD_TABLE(EID,Ename,EAddress,Emobile,CurrentDate)                 
             select  EID,Ename,EAddress,Emobile,getdate() from DELETED

End
```

Comment: mysql or Sqlserver? plz do not spam tags

Comment: Surely the net changes can be found by matching the earliest old_table with the current main_table? and the new_table is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would need to select this data inside a trigger?!

But if you need it to insert it somewhere else, then you can do this:

```
SELECT
  i.EID,
  MAX(i.Ename) AS newNameValue,
  MAX(d.Ename) AS oldNameValue,

  MAX(i.EAddress) AS newEAddressValue,
  MAX(d.EAddress) AS oldEAddressValue
FROM INSERTED AS i
INNER JOIN DELETED AS d ON i.EID = d.EID
GROUP BY i.EID
```